# Are Azure Logic Apps a superset of Power Automate?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Are `Azure Logic Apps` a superset of `Power Automate` (ignoring the licensing topic), in a way that all Power Automate Flows can be identically recreated with Logic Apps, and there is no functional or non-functional aspect (i.e. availability of Connectors, quotas, ...) that Logic Apps can't at least catch up with?

I am currently working as part of a team which already implemented some Power Automate Flows and is now struggling with the decision which one to choose as a uniform solution.

Comment: If you are working part of an IT team building workflows for end users, Logic Apps is your way to go. All your workflows are easily organized in Resource Groups. Power Automate is focused toward end users who create their own workflows and will be gone when that user leaves unless Shared with different owners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Automate and Azure Logic Apps are workflow services that can automate your processes business or system and integrate with Microsoft and 3rd party services with over 300 connectors.

`Azure Logic Apps` is not a superset of `Power Automate`, they are different services.

You can refer to [Highlight key differences between Logic Apps and Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/power-automate-vs-logic-apps#highlight-key-differences-between-logic-apps-and-power-automate).

You need to compare their differences to decide which one to use as a solution. This is based on your needs.